# Personalization on SXA Partial Design

Tags: sxa

Is it possible to use personalization on a SXA partial design? I am building a header component and want to use a personalization rule to alternate menu items shown depending on whether or not the user is authenticated. I have disabled caching entirely on the rendering for the menu items, but the partial design seems to cache the rendering per-page.

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 with SXA 1.2 rev 161216

Comment: Could you add information about you SXA version?

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak I've updated my question.

Comment: Are you using local page data (under presentation`/partial designs/partial design/data/partial designs/partial design/data` or global (under `site/data`)?
I am able to set up working POC for both SXA versions but only 1.2 require additional fix if you are using local data instead of global

Comment: I am using global data for the content - wasn't even aware of being able to place data beneath the `Partial Design` items!

Comment: Have you tried some basic rules? I used one that checks whether query string parameter is present in the URL. Works without issues. I am trying to find out whether this is incorrect configuration of personalization or some issue in SXA.

Comment: Yes, I've created a rule which checks for authenticated user to switch the datasource of a menu. It works fine with caching disabled, but not when enabled.

Comment: I recommend contacting Sitecore support. I am not sure if anybody will provide a solution for that here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue turned out to be related to a cache setting on the *parent* rendering, rather than the rendering itself.

*Don't forget:* if using personalisation, **turn off caching**. Sitecore does not do this automatically for you!

Answer (score 5):

The scenario is possible to achieve using multiple mechanisms.

1) Sitecore security on items (unauthenticated users will have no way of accessing the pages). 
SXA fully respects the Sitecore security model and you could simply revoke the read rights to everyone for the restricted items and grant it selectively to the authenticated users. The component will render the items with respect to what the Sitecore API returns.

2) Personalization + navigation filters. (if you want pages to be reachable for unauthorized users just not showing in navigation) Have 2 navigations in your header and show one for authenticated users and another one for anonymous visitors.

Add one or two navigation filters under **//Data/Navigation Filters** like this:

[image]

On the page you want to hide for anonymous visitors check the checkbox to filter the page out:

[image]

In the navigation that personalization shows to anonymous visitors pick the "Anonymous visitors" filter:[image]

3) Last option requires that you have SXA 1.3 and in this option simply specify the personalization rule on your rendering variant. This allows you to evaluate each item before it's rendered and you can set any personalization rule there:

[image]

That means you can have various fields and say e.g.

> if this field has that value and user is in this profile card - show
>   if this item is of that template and user is returning - show
>   etc.